# Use health check middleware in .NET Core Generic Host

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-middleware, .net-core-2.2

Using the .NET Core [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for an application that processes async messages.

The reason we're using the generic host instead of the .NET Core WebHost is because one of my colleagues had seen a few occasions where MassTransit (the light weight service bus framework that we're using) running as part of a .NET Core WebHost was not always shutting down gracefully on Linux after receiving a SIGTERM signal - we had to use SIGKILL to forcibly kill the process.

This application will run on Kubernetes and we want to implement a self-healing architecture using K8s liveness probes. In other .NET Core applications that use WebHost, we've used [Health Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that were introduced in .NET Core 2.2, but I don't know how to *use* middleware like this in a generic host.

In a WebHost I can configure the middleware as follows:

```
app.UseHealthChecks(appSettings.HealthChecksPath ?? "/health");
```

How would I go about doing this if using .NET Core Generic Host...

Kind regards.

Comment: The docs is a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @LGSon not sure you understood my question properly. I need to use .NET core 2.2. generic host (for reasons outlined), but hosting HTTP accessible endpoints such as health checks at /health and Prometheus metrics at /metrics are not suitable for .NET 2.2 & generic host - see answer below. As mentioned happy to be proven wrong, if there's an easier way...

Comment: I do understand. First off, FYI, "Generic Host" will replace "Web Host" in a future release (ASP.NET Core 3.0) and act as the primary host API in both HTTP and non-HTTP scenarios, and since 2.2 is not on LTS you will have to move to 3.0 before Dec. 2019 (or lose support), you might want to take that into account (also 3.0 RC scheduled for July, GA in Sept.).

Comment: Second, if you provide a [mcve] so we can see what/how you do, someone might have a proper answer. And if not, and given you did post a self answer, other users might find this very useful, though it needs a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by using a HttpListener based health-check server - happy to be proven wrong, but AFAIK, Kestrel / ASP.NET Core middleware is not suitable for .NET 2.2 & generic host.

see [here](https://github.com/yesmarket/HealthCheckHostedService) for code.

Comment: _"see here for code"_ is not how we do at SO. The essential part of the code should be **within** the answer, or it dies when that external link dies, and with that its usefulness for future users (which SO is all about).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create custom http listener. Here is I believe how its intended  ( somedbcheck.cs class implements interface: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.IHealthCheck):

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog(logger)
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                //Configure generic host services
            }
        )
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
        //This is where you are setting up webserver
            webBuilder.UseKestrel((c, options) =>
            {
                options.ListenAnyIP(config.Healthcheckport, listenoption =>
                {
                    listenoption.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                });
            });
        })
        .ConfigureWebHost(aa =>
        {
            //here you are specifying more details regarding endpoint mapping
            aa.UseStartup<WebHostStartup>();
        })
        .Build();
        
        
        
public class WebHostStartup
{
    private readonly AppSettings config;

    public WebHostStartup()
    {
        this.config = new AppSettings().GetSettings();  //your own parsed settings if you need it
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    //set up services associated with the webserver
        services.AddRouting();
        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddTypeActivatedCheck<SomeDbCheck>(nameof(SomeDbCheck)
                , failureStatus: HealthStatus.Unhealthy
                , tags: new[] { "startup", "ready" }
                , args: new object[] { config.ConnectionString })
            .AddCheck<LivenessCheck>(nameof(LivenessCheck), tags: new[] { "live" });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
    //Here set up the routing
        app.UseWhen(context => context.Connection.LocalPort == config.Healthcheckport,
            applicationBuilder =>
            {
                applicationBuilder.UseRouting();
                
                //applicationBuilder.UseAuthentication();
                applicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
                    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/startup", new HealthCheckOptions
                    {
                        Predicate = healthCheck => healthCheck.Tags.Contains("startup")
                    });

                    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/ready", new HealthCheckOptions
                    {
                        Predicate = healthCheck => healthCheck.Tags.Contains("ready")
                    });

                    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions
                    {
                        Predicate = healthCheck => healthCheck.Tags.Contains("live")
                    });
                });
            });
    }
}
```